# Creating a blog on my companies new website using Wordpress but I have sidebar issues

Tags: php, css, sidebar, front-end, blog

As said in the title, I am creating a blog on my companies new website using Wordpress but I have sidebar issues.

The website is only in production phase at the moment.
The Link is so you can see is:
http://madhousecreative.co.uk/completegroup/Blog/

Heres an image of what it is currently.
[image]

Whenever I try to move the sidebar up it messes up and the bit move up dissapears.
Heres another image to show you what I mean:

[image]

I hope the images help explain what I am trying to say.

Im really stuck on this so I hope someone can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do three things:

- firstly, your markup is incorrect, take the container_24 div the main content sits in and make it grid_17 so it doesn't take up the entire width of the container div.
- The sidebar needs to go in the container div along with the content, else it will be pushed downwards by the container div
- Because of the above issues, you've introduced numerous negative and left-hand margins. If you remove these margins and do the above, you should have a vast improvement.

remember where grid systems are concerned you have a container div, which contains all the columns, and the columns all add up to the full width of that container.

Comment: cheers for your help it helped a lot. It worked for the original problem but it created a new issue, which is the footer has raised up. if you go to the link again in the description you'll see what i mean.  Any advice?

Comment: You need to clear your floats. Instead of <div class="grid_6><div id="sidebar">, try <div id="sidebar" class="grid_6">, if not add clearing elements/classes

Comment: You've added <div style="height:700px;"></div> to your page, this is incorrect, add <div style="clear:both;"></div> instead, and your issues should all be fixed

Comment: Your original question has also been added, if you could mark this answer as the correct answer?